# How can I set space between responsive div?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to `css` and wrote this html code:

```
<div class="col-1">A</div>
        <div class="col-1">B</div>
        <div class="col-1">C</div>
        <div class="col-1">D</div>
        <div class="col-1">E</div>
        <div class="col-1">F</div>
        <div class="col-1">G</div>
        <div class="col-1">H</div>
        <div class="col-1">I</div>
        <div class="col-1">J</div>
        <div class="col-1">K</div>
        <div class="col-1">L</div>
```

and this is my `css`:

```
.col-1 {
            width: 58px;
            background-color: chocolate;
        }
```

write up code for achive this output:
[CLICK TO SHOW](http://185.126.201.42/output.png)

but my result is this:
[THIS LINK](http://185.126.201.42/otupout2.png)

How can i solve that problem?thanks.

Comment: Image not upload please wait upload that

Comment: dont give background to direct to col, just add child element and give background to child, so that you are able to see space between div tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add a margin `margin: 1px;` to your `col-1` elements like this:

```css
.col-1 {
  width: 58px;
  background-color: chocolate;
  margin: 1px;
  /*I just added this to make them inline */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-1">A</div>
<div class="col-1">B</div>
<div class="col-1">C</div>
<div class="col-1">D</div>
<div class="col-1">E</div>
<div class="col-1">F</div>
<div class="col-1">G</div>
<div class="col-1">H</div>
<div class="col-1">I</div>
<div class="col-1">J</div>
<div class="col-1">K</div>
<div class="col-1">L</div>
```

It will give you the expected results, note that you can edit it with the wanted pixels.

Comment: @chertchertopert great, glad it helps.

Comment: in your snippet, the columns are displayed below each other for me

Answer (score 0):

I would reccommend using the new flexbox layout. Browser support is pretty good already (http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) and you can add some vendor prefixes if needed.

```css
.col-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 58px;
  background-color: chocolate;
  margin: 0px 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-wrapper">
  <div class="col-1">A</div>
  <div class="col-1">B</div>
  <div class="col-1">C</div>
  <div class="col-1">D</div>
  <div class="col-1">E</div>
  <div class="col-1">F</div>
  <div class="col-1">G</div>
  <div class="col-1">H</div>
  <div class="col-1">I</div>
  <div class="col-1">J</div>
  <div class="col-1">K</div>
  <div class="col-1">L</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main{float: left; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; background: #eee; box-sizing: border-box;}
.col-1{float: left; width: 8%; box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #000; margin: 1%; background: #3C3}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
     .main{float: left; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; background: #eee; box-sizing: border-box;}
   .col-1{float: left; width: 8%; box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #000; margin: 1%; background: #3C3}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
  <div class="col-1">A</div>
        <div class="col-1">B</div>
        <div class="col-1">C</div>
        <div class="col-1">D</div>
        <div class="col-1">E</div>
        <div class="col-1">F</div>
        <div class="col-1">G</div>
        <div class="col-1">H</div>
        <div class="col-1">I</div>
        <div class="col-1">J</div>
</div>        

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Responsive RWD  html css